# OpenGL: glRotate: determining the 'angle' component

Tags: math, opengl

I need some help with math and OpenGL.

I want to make some object follow another one, that is, turn its face to another object every time the former moves. So I learned about glRotate.

I thought I would obtain the (x, y, z) of the former everytime it moves and then send its coordinates to another function which should update the 'facing to' property of the latter. But, how do I find the 'angle' parameter to glRotate based on both new and old direction of the follower object?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks for you time.

Comment: Such a rotation is generally not unique. Do you already know the axis you want to rotate around? Because then it would be.

Comment: Around the y-axis would be nice for starters. Can you show me? But, what is required to do around the x-axis as well, for instance?

Comment: I posted something for the Y axis. Doing it for both Y and X is more tricky since you also need to combine the rotations in the right way (I assume you want pitch and yaw rotation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that your observer is at `0,0,0` and your have an old target position `O` and a new target position `N`.

Then the angle difference around the Y axis in radians is:

```
float angle = atan2(N.z,N.x) - atan2(O.z,O.x);
```

Since `glRotate` accepts degrees, you want convert that to degrees:

```
angle = (angle * 180.f)/M_PI;
```

How does this work? You project both vectors to the XZ plane. I just ignore the x component for that. Then you take their angle respective the X axis (That arctan does that) and take the difference.

**Edit:** Fixed the angle computation, thanks to ja72 for pointing out that it was catastrophically broken.

Comment: Wouldn't you want an `arctan()` to get the angle. Or is a small angle approximation sufficient for this application?

Comment: @ja72: A you're right, it's not even an angle yet - I'll fix it ASAP.